# Unable to serialize Quartz, java.io.NotSerializableException: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler

Tags: java, serialization, quartz-scheduler

When trying to serialize the scheduled event, i am getting

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
```

Job is scheduled as follows

```
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();

    job.setName(jobName);
    job.setGroup("my group");
    job.setJobClass(Event.class);

    SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
    trigger.setStartTime(new Date(momentInTime.inMillis()));
    trigger.setName("trigger" + index);

    if (shouldRunOnce()) {
        trigger.setRepeatCount(0);
    } else {
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(repeatFrequency.inMillis());
        trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
    }

    scheduleManager.getScheduler().scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

How can this be avoided please?

Comment: Can you post more lines of the stacktrace?

Comment: @Zaske Done. Thanks for looking at this

Comment: can you post the source code of Event?

Comment: There is nothing to it, `implements Job`, sleeps for 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Event class does not implement the Serializable interface). 

I see no reason why to serialize the scheduler itself, so I suspect this is the reason 
 And it kinda make sense as Quartz scheduler has to store the jobs somehow.

Comment: Event is serializable. It appears that `org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler` is not